# How to change UIPageControl dots

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder, uipagecontrol

I've seen apps (e.g. meebo) that have different indicators on UIPageControls instead of the default white circles.

is there an easy way to do this? I've read the docs for UIPageControls and it seems that there is no methods to replace the images.

Comment: [**HHPageControl**](https://github.com/hemangshah/HHPageController)

Comment: This is not a dupe of the other question: here we want to know how to change the dots; the linked "dupe" just wants to change the colour. My solution is appended to Aragon's below.

Comment: Since this "dupe" does not accept answers anymore I will comment another solution. If you just want to change the size of the dots you can use pagecontrol.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);

Answer (score 21):

You can achieve this by making the following steps:

1- Create a custom class that inherits from UIPageControl.

2- Assign this class to the required UIPageControl that you want to change its dots.

3- Put the following code inside your custom UIPageControl class.

Put this in the customClass.m file:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self)
    {
        activeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"active_dot.png"];
        inactiveImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"inactive_dot.png"];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)updateDots
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.subviews count]; i++)
    {
        UIImageView* dot = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        dot.frame = CGRectMake(dot.frame.origin.x, dot.frame.origin.y, 14, 14.5);
        if (i == self.currentPage)
            dot.image = activeImage;
        else
            dot.image = inactiveImage;
    }
}

-(void)setCurrentPage:(NSInteger)page
{
    [super setCurrentPage:page];
    [self updateDots];
}
```

Put this in the customClass.h file

```
{
    UIImage* activeImage;
    UIImage* inactiveImage;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage* activeImage;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage* inactiveImage;
```

5- Just set the current page of your UIPageControl in the class that you put the page control inside it using the following line:

```
[self.pageControl setCurrentPage:number];
```

remember to set the current page in the viewDidLoad() method in the view of that UIPageControl is inside it.

When the view loaded the UIPageControl images will be set.

Comment: dots are UIView objects in iOS7, so need to update the code.

Comment: I've updated the code for Aragon's updateDots: method to support iOS 7. See my answer below.

Comment: Curses, answers are closed, even though I like this solution better than the one on the linked page for which this is supposedly a dupe.  Simply put, a PageControl's subviews are UIViews, so I'm injecting a UIImageView into them:

Comment: -(void)updateDots
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.subviews count]; i++)
    {
        UIView* dot = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        UIImageView * newDot = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(dot.frame.origin.x, dot.frame.origin.y, 14, 14)];
        
        if (i == self.currentPage) {
            newDot.image = self.activeImage;
        }
        else {
            newDot.image = self.inactiveImage;
        }
        
        [dot addSubview:newDot];
    }
}

Comment: Aragon's answer combined with Aaron Vegh's comment is a working solution.

Comment: can i have the final working solution?

Answer (score 4):

There is not public API to change the images. You can take a look at [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20171224020347/http://apptech.next-munich.com/2010/04/customizing-uipagecontrols-looks.html), that describes a method to customize the [UIPageControl](https://web.archive.org/web/20100729152759/http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html).