# uipageview controller cannot update dot images using iOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I have created custom class with subclasss of **UIPageControl**

**customClass.h**

```
@interface customclass : UIPageControl
{
    UIImage* activeImage;
    UIImage* inactiveImage;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage* activeImage;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage* inactiveImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageController;

@end
```

**customclass.m file**

```
@implementation customclass
@synthesize activeImage,inactiveImage;
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self)
    {
       activeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dots.png"];
       inactiveImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"off.png"];


    }
    return self;
}
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        activeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dots.png"];
        inactiveImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"off.png"];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)updateDots
{
        for (int i = 0; i < [self.subviews count]; i++)
        {
            UIImageView * dot = [self imageViewForSubview:  [self.subviews objectAtIndex: i]];
            if (i == self.currentPage) dot.image = activeImage;
            else dot.image = inactiveImage;
        }

}

- (UIImageView *) imageViewForSubview: (UIView *) view
{
    UIImageView * dot = nil;
    if ([view isKindOfClass: [UIView class]])
    {
        for (UIView* subview in view.subviews)
        {
            if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
            {
                dot = (UIImageView *)subview;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (dot == nil)
        {
            dot = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 17,17)];
            [view addSubview:dot];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dot = (UIImageView *) view;
    }

    return dot;
}


-(void)setCurrentPage:(NSInteger)page
{
    [super setCurrentPage:page];
    [self updateDots];
}
```

the following line never executed.I am using iOS 8.3

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.subviews count]; i++)
```

here never get into that `loop`..

i dont know whats going on here..

i am following this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673827/how-to-change-uipagecontrol-dots)

i have called at my uipageviewcontroller like this...

```
pageControl=[[customclass alloc]init];
    [pageControl setCurrentPage:0];
```

Comment: Where did you call that function?

Comment: i have called at my uipageviewcontroller like this...

 pageControl=[[customclass alloc]init];
    [pageControl setCurrentPage:0];

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't think you need an `UIPageControl` in your custom `UIPageControl`.

Then you need to set the number of page of your custom page control, so in the `viewDidLoad` of your `UIViewController`, you will have something like that (I recommend you to change the name of your custom `UIPageControl` with `MyPageControl` for example):

```
customclass *pc = [[customclass alloc] init];
pc.center = self.view.center; // Set the position here
[pc setNumberOfPages:10];
[pc setCurrentPage:0];
[self.view addSubview:pc];
```

Finally, what about this other solution:

```
UIPageControl *pc = [[UIPageControl alloc] init]; 
pc.center = CGPointMake(200, 200); // Set the position here
pc.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dots"]];
pc.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"off"]];
[pc setNumberOfPages:10];
[pc setCurrentPage:0];
```

Comment: thanks for comment but not working .what is the default size of dots?how do increse it?