# Custom PageControl image - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, pagecontrol

I am trying to set an image for UIPageControl dots.

I need to change the default dots, instead of that I need an image.
I used the below code

```
self.pageCtrl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.init(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Page Indicator_Selected")!)
self.pageCtrl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.init(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Page Indicator_Normal")!)
```

I could set the image in Pagecontrol but, it is overlapping with default dots.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom UIPageControl with dot images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38869171/custom-uipagecontrol-with-dot-images)

Answer (score 10):

The code Politta suggested is not working on iOS 14 as Apple had introduced some new APIs for UIPageControll.

Take look here for details [UIPageControls New APIs](https://medium.com/better-programming/take-a-look-at-ios-14s-new-uipagecontrol-3207a10212b9)

Here is the updated code supporting iOS 14

```
class CustomPageControl: UIPageControl {

@IBInspectable var currentPageImage: UIImage?

@IBInspectable var otherPagesImage: UIImage?

override var numberOfPages: Int {
    didSet {
        updateDots()
    }
}

override var currentPage: Int {
    didSet {
        updateDots()
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        defaultConfigurationForiOS14AndAbove()
    } else {
        pageIndicatorTintColor = .clear
        currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .clear
        clipsToBounds = false
    }
}

private func defaultConfigurationForiOS14AndAbove() {
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        for index in 0..<numberOfPages {
            let image = index == currentPage ? currentPageImage : otherPagesImage
            setIndicatorImage(image, forPage: index)
        }

        // give the same color as "otherPagesImage" color.
        pageIndicatorTintColor = .gray
        
        // give the same color as "currentPageImage" color.
        currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .red 
        /*
         Note: If Tint color set to default, Indicator image is not showing. So, give the same tint color based on your Custome Image.
        */
    }
}

private func updateDots() {
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        defaultConfigurationForiOS14AndAbove()
    } else {
        for (index, subview) in subviews.enumerated() {
            let imageView: UIImageView
            if let existingImageview = getImageView(forSubview: subview) {
                imageView = existingImageview
            } else {
                imageView = UIImageView(image: otherPagesImage)
                
                imageView.center = subview.center
                subview.addSubview(imageView)
                subview.clipsToBounds = false
            }
            imageView.image = currentPage == index ? currentPageImage : otherPagesImage
        }
    }
}

private func getImageView(forSubview view: UIView) -> UIImageView? {
    if let imageView = view as? UIImageView {
        return imageView
    } else {
        let view = view.subviews.first { (view) -> Bool in
            return view is UIImageView
        } as? UIImageView

        return view
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This working but color effect is not working properly

Comment: Try with an image that has a transparent background and get the correct RGB or hex. That might help.

Comment: I tried, It gives different color on first time load and after scrolling It works fine.

Comment: Seems like your layout is not updating properly. Try with layoutIfNeeded() or some delay.

Comment: It's updating issue is that first time it show opposite tint color

Answer (score 4):

I improved Agent Smith's answer to work with any number of pages. You can customize the images on xibs/storyboards.

```
class CustomPageControl: UIPageControl {

@IBInspectable var currentPageImage: UIImage?

@IBInspectable var otherPagesImage: UIImage?

override var numberOfPages: Int {
    didSet {
        updateDots()
    }
}

override var currentPage: Int {
    didSet {
        updateDots()
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    pageIndicatorTintColor = .clear
    currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .clear
    clipsToBounds = false
}

private func updateDots() {

    for (index, subview) in subviews.enumerated() {
        let imageView: UIImageView
        if let existingImageview = getImageView(forSubview: subview) {
            imageView = existingImageview
        } else {
            imageView = UIImageView(image: otherPagesImage)

            imageView.center = subview.center
            subview.addSubview(imageView)
            subview.clipsToBounds = false
        }
        imageView.image = currentPage == index ? currentPageImage : otherPagesImage
    }
}

private func getImageView(forSubview view: UIView) -> UIImageView? {
    if let imageView = view as? UIImageView {
        return imageView
    } else {
        let view = view.subviews.first { (view) -> Bool in
            return view is UIImageView
        } as? UIImageView

        return view
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This one is not working for iOS14, subviews count is always 1

Answer (score 1):

This approach works for me. I create a custom pageControl class and change the images for dots to be any custom image.

In the code below I changed the image for the first dot in pageControl with any custom image.

You can change **updateDots()** method as per your needs.

Hope it helps!!!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let pageControl = CustomPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 104, height: 40))
    pageControl.numberOfPages = 5
    pageControl.currentPage = 0
    self.view.addSubview(pageControl)
}


class CustomPageControl: UIPageControl {


var imageToBeReplacedByDot: UIImage {
    return // Image you want to replace with dots
}
var circleImage: UIImage {

    return //Default Image
}


override var numberOfPages: Int {
    didSet {
        updateDots()
    }
}

override var currentPage: Int {
    didSet {
        updateDots()
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.clear
    self.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.clear
    self.clipsToBounds = false
}

func updateDots() {
    var i = 0
    for view in self.subviews {
        var imageView = self.imageView(forSubview: view)
        if imageView == nil {
            if i == 0 {
                imageView = UIImageView(image: imageToBeReplacedByDot)
            } else {
                imageView = UIImageView(image: circleImage)
            }
            imageView!.center = view.center
            view.addSubview(imageView!)
            view.clipsToBounds = false
        }
        if i == self.currentPage {
            imageView!.alpha = 1.0
        } else {
            imageView!.alpha = 0.5
        }
        i += 1
    }
}

fileprivate func imageView(forSubview view: UIView) -> UIImageView? {
    var dot: UIImageView?
    if let dotImageView = view as? UIImageView {
        dot = dotImageView
    } else {
        for foundView in view.subviews {
            if let imageView = foundView as? UIImageView {
                dot = imageView
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return dot
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Supporting **iOS 14**, our PageControl subclass, simply we can do this:

```
    override var numberOfPages: Int {
        didSet {
            self._updateIndicators()
        }
    }
    
    override var currentPage: Int {
        didSet {
            self._updateIndicators()
        }
    }

    private func _updateIndicators() {
        var indicators: [UIView] = []
        
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            indicators = self.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.subviews ?? []
        } else {
            indicators = self.subviews
        }
        
        for (index, indicator) in indicators.enumerated() {
            let image = self.currentPage == index ? UIImage.init(named: "Page Indicator_Normal") : UIImage.init(named: "Page Indicator_Selected")
            if let dot = indicator as? UIImageView {
                dot.image = image
                
            } else {
                let imageView = UIImageView.init(image: image)
                indicator.addSubview(imageView)
                // here you can add some constraints to fix the imageview to his superview
            }
        }
    }
```